# Detecting a finger snap(basically trying to replicate infinity gauntlet)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, sensors

I am trying to make an **infinity gauntlet**. So it's obvious it should have a ***snap*** feature(which will switch of a light,motor or whatever). But I don't know how to go about sense this snap. I thought of two ideas: one detecting the snap sound but since I will be wearing a glove it can't be heard loudly, second is, trying to detect the pressure between thumb and middle finger and calculating velocity of middle finger during the snap. And I even found EMG sensor can be used but it's too costly so suggest me best way possible with proper explanation

P.S: This is my first ever Arduino project

Comment: How about a piezo sensor on the middle fingertip that detects the sharp blow of the finger snap? (plus some electronics to bring the signal into the right voltage range for a logic signal)

Comment: you could always simulate the finger snap by the use of an appropriate sound effect

Comment: i just checked to see how else you could detect a finger snap ..  some of the tendons on the inside of the wrist make a distinct motion ... perhaps a wrist band with integrated pressure sensors could pick up the tendon motion

Comment: > "This is my first ever Arduino project". Good luck. Be open to "simpler" solutions, too. E.g. building a switch by touching thumb with another finger.